# Multiple Download Issue in Dropbox SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, core-api

Core[API] for integrating the Dropbox SDK into my iOS Application.
I have problem dealing with Multiple download with Dropbox:
I have two files in my Dropbox cloud Storages. The file names Are: 1.txt,2.txt. If I put 1.txt file in download, 1.txt is successfully downloading, Suddenly if I put 2.txt file in download, **The First one is Aborted** and **Second one started**. So how can I perform two threads simultaneously? I used the following code to download the file from Dropbox.

```
-(void)startDownload :(CFileAdaptor *) cf_in
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
        // pass Filename from adapter
    NSString *localPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:cf_in.m_nFileNameProperty];
    // pass path from adapter
    NSString *path = [cf_in.m_oMetaDataProperty valueForKey:@"path"];
    [[self restClient] loadFile:path intoPath:localPath];
}
```

Comment: This should just work. How do you know that it's not?

Comment: Nope. Its working single file download. But not working for Multiple file download @smarx

Comment: Are you trying to load both files into the same localPath? That could be the issue?

Comment: Not Same localPath. This will create with help of different filename. so it will be different. Forexample. documentsdir\1.txt,documentsdir\2.txt. @LeahCulver

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What's the error?